# Transfer weight painting

Tags: weight-painting

I want to transfer weight painting from one character to another almost identical. I have tried with datatrasnfer modifier, but it didn't help me.  I use Blender 3.2.

Comment: Try to use the data transfer operation instead of the modifier.

Comment: The modifier should work, what was the setting of the modifier?

Comment: @moonboots yes, it should, but much more difficult to understand what is happening in case of problem (or in need of tuning something).

Comment: Okay I'll try. Thank you!

Comment: If it doesn't work, please give more details or even share your file

Comment: Hi! How can I share my file? I didn't figure out how to solve the problem

Comment: jse this https://blend-exchange.com/ and paste the link here.